# How to put a unicode character in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, unicode, binding

I'm trying to do this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, 
                          Converter={StaticResource stringFormatConverter}, 
                          ConverterParameter='&\u2014{0}'}" />
```

To get a — to appear in front of the text.  It doesn't work.  What should I be doing here?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Since XAML is an XML file format you could try the XML character escape. So instead of writing `&\u2014`, you could write `&#x2014;` instead.

Comment: thank you.  I tried &mdash; and \u2014, but not that.  It worked.

Comment: You were close, in hexa &#x20ac; and in decimal unicode &#8364; you'll get and Euro :)

Comment: Yes, but what if you want a UTF-32 character, like the musical notes in the Symbola font which are above 0x10000?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However this only worked for me when I put my unicode character directly inside Text="...". When using a Binding with my ViewModel I had to use a string variable containing "\u2014".

Comment: @RuudvanGaal: see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73924909/147511) below for the simple **UTF-32** syntax in **XAML**...

Comment: Note the trailing `;`

Answer (score 11):

In xaml I did it like this:

```
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="start" Margin="5" Click="start_Click">
        <TextBlock Name="test" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Y_Yoga;Component/Resources/#FontAwesome">&#xF04B;</TextBlock>
    </Button>
```

Hope to be helpful!

Answer (score 7):

I came to this page for some other reason, but this does not include the easiest and the obvious solution.

This is what I do.

Maintain a static class with all the Unicode values.

```
 public static class Icons
{
    public const string IconName = "\u2014";
}
```

And then just bind it wherever you need it.

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static resources:Icons.IconName}" FontFamily="..."/>
```

This also helps you out with maintenance, all icons would be in one place to manage.

Answer (score 3):

[From Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970677(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Markup files that are created in Microsoft Visual Studio are
>   automatically saved in the Unicode UTF-8 file format, which means that
>   most special characters, such as accent marks, are encoded correctly.
>   However, there is a set of commonly-used special characters that are
>   handled differently. These special characters follow the World Wide
>   Web Consortium (W3C) XML standard for encoding.

What this means is that you can do zalgo for all you care

[image]

Bit of code that is relevant:

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" FontWeight="ExtraBlack">STAGE:M&#x363;&#x36d;&#x363;&#x33e;  V&#x363;&#x365;&#x36d;&#x35b;&#x364;&#x36e;&#x365;&#x368;&#x365;&#x367;&#x33e;</Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the file as UTF-8. In Visual Studio, you can do this by going "File" → "Advanced Save Options".

Answer (score 0):

The **UTF-32** syntax in **WPF/XAML** is like so:    `&#x000F1B0A;`

```
<TextBlock Text="foo &#x000F1B0A; bar"
           FontFamily="Material Design Icons" />
```

[image]

This example is using the [Material Design Icons](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign-Font) desktop font (glyph dump [here](https://pictogrammers.github.io/@mdi/font/6.9.96/))