# How can I find out the XAML codes used for characters in fontAwesome?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

In unicode I have a character that I specify by `"\uf2fc"`  Can someone tell me how I can go about converting the unicode form show in the FO docs to those I can use in XAML? The XAML values used to be listed on the web pages but it no longer lists them and just gives the Unicode.

https://fontawesome.com/icons/rectangle-wide?style=regular

Note that the new versions of the cheat sheet don't include the XAML codes like the old versions did.

https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet/pro

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367341/4984832

Comment: [cheat sheet](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/), just change the ver# in the url for your needs.

Comment: Those cheat sheets are for the old version of font awesome.  The cheat sheets for the new version don't include the XAML codes unfortunately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367202/how-to-put-a-unicode-character-in-xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to implement a class "FontAwesome.cs" and then fill it with static variables:

```
public class FontAwesome
{
    public static string FAGlass = "\uf000";
    public static string FAMusic = "\uf001";
    public static string FASearch = "\uf002";
    public static string FAEnvelopeO = "\uf003";
    public static string FAHeart = "\uf004";
    public static string FAStar = "\uf005";
    public static string FAStarO = "\uf006";
    public static string FAUser = "\uf007";
    public static string FAFilm = "\uf008";
    public static string FAThLarge = "\uf009";
    public static string FATh = "\uf00a";
    public static string FAThList = "\uf00b";
    public static string FACheck = "\uf00c";
    public static string FATimes = "\uf00d";
    public static string FASearchPlus = "\uf00e";
    ...
}
```

Then whenever needed, you can access it in your xaml with:

```
<Label Text="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesome.FABriefcase}" />
```

Note that this requires you to include the class in your Xaml:

```
xmlns:fontAwesome="clr-namespace:MyApp.Globals;assembly=MyApp"
```