# Binding Image.Source to string with umlauts - file not found

Tags: wpf, binding

How can I bind Image.Source to a filename that contains umlauts?

```
<StackPanel>
    <Image Source="{Binding Image1}" />
    <Image Source="{Binding Image2}" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
// DataContext
public string Image1 { get; set; } = "/test.png";
public string Image2 { get; set; } = "/testä.png";
```

Both images are included via build action "content" and "copy if newer".

Image1 is visible at runtime, while Image2 is not. Image2 produces the following error in the output window:

> 'TargetDefaultValueConverter' converter failed to convert value
>   **'/testä.png'** (type 'String'); fallback value will be used, if
>   available. BindingExpression:Path=Image2; DataItem='MainWindow'
>   (Name=''); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is
>   'Source' (type 'ImageSource') IOException:'System.IO.IOException: Die
>   Ressource **"test%c3%a4.png"** kann nicht gefunden werden.

I tried some versions from here ([How to put a unicode character in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367202/how-to-put-a-unicode-character-in-xaml)) without success.

**Edit**

Apparently, `{Binding Image1}` turns "/test.png" into "pack://application:,,,/WpfImageBindingUmlauts;component/test.png", rather than searching on the file system (as I had suspected).

**Solution 1**
I managed to force the binding looking on the file system by using a full file path like "C:\test.png". This works also for "C:\testä.png".

**Solution 2**
For @Andrew Stephens reported to not experience the same problem, I was curious and found that the previously mentioned code works perfectly, when using the build action "resource". (Background: I was using build action "content" in the first place, to include the png into clickonce deployment)

Comment: I've just reproduced this and it works for me! Now, if I delete the file, I get the same "converter" error as you, but the latter part is a FileNotFoundException not an IOException like yours: FileNotFoundException:'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Temp\testä.png'.
File name: 'C:\Temp\testä.png'. Not sure if that helps you at all?!

Comment: This is unexpected. Does your system also search the file name "test%c3%a4.png" ?

Comment: Apologies, I was originally using an absolute path (which works), but I discovered that relative paths fail like yours. It seems to relate to the `Image.Source` property's built-in string converter. You would have to write your own converter to handle it. See this answer and the one following it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17267458/981831

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I'm ok using the absolute path and do not bother creating an own IValueConverter.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning a `string`, you could return a `BitmapImage` from your source property:

```
public BitmapImage Image2 { get; set; } = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/testä.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then there will be no possibly failing converter involved.

Comment: You are right, that should technically work. I have not mentioned in the question, but I have a filterable ListView that holds thousands of such images. Holding everything in RAM is maybe too much.